# central control timer using php any jquery or WebSocket OR node.js

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, websocket, real-time

I want to design central control timer with php and any other client side script.

[image]

the basically things that need to keep in mind is that : timer will be visible on my website,so may be hundred of user are currently logged in to my website. Now whenever admin **reset** the timer on the same point it should reflect to all the client machine. so basic is need to keep **synchronous** timing all the machine.

**What I did**

I have used client side **countdown timer** (http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) 
and in background I am **calling ajax on every second to check reset is pressed or not**.
but the problem is its **not keeping synchronous in all the client machine**.
some time time gape between two machine is marked.so how to implement it?

code:

```
$('#shortly').countdown({until: shortly,  
    onExpiry: liftOff, onTick: watchCountdown}); 

$('#shortlyStart').click(function() { 
    shortly = new Date(); 
    shortly.setSeconds(shortly.getSeconds() + 5.5); 
    $('#shortly').countdown('option', {until: shortly}); 
}); 

function liftOff() { 
    alert('We have lift off!'); 
} 

function watchCountdown(periods) { 
    $('#monitor').text('Just ' + periods[5] + ' minutes and ' + 
        periods[6] + ' seconds to go'); 
}
```

Comment: Why not have your reset send an expiry timestamp instead, then your client can do the math and regardless of when it realises a reset is required it can set the timer based on the local clock in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**timerset.php. This file creates the file for the server side to push the finish time.**

```
<?php
$year=htmlspecialchars($_GET['year']);
$month=htmlspecialchars($_GET['month']);
$day=htmlspecialchars($_GET['day']);
$hour=htmlspecialchars($_GET['hour']+2);//NBNBNB the +2 changes according to YOUR timezone.
$minute=htmlspecialchars($_GET['minute']);
$second=htmlspecialchars($_GET['second']);

$timestring=$year.":".$month.":".$day.":".$hour.":".$minute.":".$second;
echo $timestring."<br/>";
$filename = 'timerserver.php';
$file = fopen($filename, 'w');
rewind($file);
fwrite($file,"<?php\n");
fwrite($file, "header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');\n");
fwrite($file, "header('Cache-Control: no-cache');\n");
fwrite($file, "header('connection:keep-alive');\n");
fwrite($file, "\$starttime=\"$timestring\";\n");
fwrite($file, "echo \"data:{\$starttime}\\n\\n\";\n");
fwrite($file, "ob_flush();");
fwrite($file,"flush();");
fwrite($file,"sleep(3);");
fwrite($file,"?>\n");
fflush($file);
ftruncate($file, ftell($file));
fclose($file);
flush();
?>
```

timer.php. This file receives the finish time and updates the displayed time.

```
<html>
<header>
</header>
<body>
<script>

var source = new EventSource("timerserver.php");
var mystarttime="00:00";

source.onmessage = function(event)
{
    mystarttime=event.data;
};

setInterval(function () {test(mystarttime)}, 1000);

function test(intime)
{
    var timestring=intime;
    var split = timestring.split(':');

    var currentdate=new Date();
    var finishtime=new Date(split[0],split[1]-1,split[2],split[3],split[4],split[5],0);

    var timediff=new Date(finishtime-currentdate);

    var year=timediff.getUTCFullYear();
    var minutes=timediff.getUTCMinutes();
    var seconds=timediff.getUTCSeconds();
    var currentMinutes = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2);
    var currentSeconds = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2);
    if (year<1970)
    {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Time is up"
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = currentMinutes+":"+currentSeconds;
}
</script>
<div id="result">Fetching time...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

timerform.php . One method of updating the time.

```
<?php
echo "<b>NB : Time is in UTC Timezone</b><br/><hr/>";
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$currentdatetime=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$year=date("Y");
$month=date("m");
$day=date("j");
$hour=date("H");
$minute=date("i");
$second=0;
echo $currentdatetime."<hr/>";
?>
<form action="timerreset.php" method="GET">
Year <input name="year" value="<?php echo $year;?>"/><br/>
Month <input name="month" value="<?php echo $month;?>"/><br/>
Day <input name="day" value="<?php echo $day;?>"/><br/><br/>
Hour <input name="hour" value="<?php echo $hour;?>"/><br/>
Minute <input name="minute" value="<?php echo $minute+1;?>"/><br/>
Second <input name="second" value="<?php echo $second;?>"/><br/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
flush();
?>
```

**NB**, Use UTC time to cater for different clients in different timezones.

I have the above code working on both my localhost (Windows) and at SouthCoastHosting (Linux), so let me know if you have any problems.

To use it open a tab to southcoasthosting.com/timer/timerform.php and another tab to southcoasthosting.com/timer/timer.php. Use the timer form to change the finish time and you will see the time chage in timer.php. Due to the nature of EventSource there will always be at best a 3 second delay before updating the timer. Depending on your clients connection speed to the server there may be further delays. I chose to send a finish time so that the client will not lag due to these delays.

I hope that all makes sense. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: Hey where is timerserver.php?

Comment: timerserver.php gets created by 'timerset.php'.

Comment: the demo working great, now here we have added 3 second delay,if i will remove that it will executed on every second,how is that possible to execute it the gap of microseconds ?

Comment: In the line 'setInterval(function () {test(mystarttime)}, 1000);' the timer will get updates at whatever time period you specify. 1000 is 1 second, 100 is 1/10th of a second, etc. The 3 second delay for loading the reset from the server side cannot be changed as it is 'built in' to the EventSource function. There are ways around that, but they tend to cause more problems than the solve, but I do not see why you should want to 'reset' in microseconds???

Comment: actually I have to implement real time system in php,its bidding website which contains 30 seconds timer,now if any one will bid any amount reset timer to 30 seconds again,but that not happening in our demo,i have tested on 5 system and seems 1 second delay between some system

Comment: If you are hoping that web client can get update in an instant I think you may be hoping for a bit much. Network lag and internet lag will make sure that that is impossible. Even the processes running on a clients PC will make sure that it will not update the web browser every time in an instant (microseconds) due to it's background processes. If it's a bid process I assume you need to update a database with new bids. This in itself will take up time which will vary a bit depending on the server speed/background processes.

Comment: As for the 1 second delay, that can be cause by the 'time' the client opens the webpage in the first place. The time it takes to reload from the server side will depend on the time the page was opened. If all clients open the page at exactly the same time you should not see a delay, except of course for the increased load on the server, so you cannot win. All I can suggest if you take this small delay into account. Add for example 5 seconds to the time and do not allow new bids with 5 seconds to go. Then the bidders will know to place the bid in good time.

Comment: Yeah thats right Gavin, hey i have one more query is that can we use session in websocket? because I have set session in daemon file and using that in our timerserver but its showing blank session

Comment: I would need a bit more info than that to go on regarding websocket. As much af I have set up websocket once before, I am no expert on it.

Comment: Hey Gavin if I have to pass more than one value here
echo "data:{$starttime}\n\n";
so here how can i pass other variable?

Comment: That's almost another question, and not east to answer in a short comment. Take a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/, it has an example of multiple variables. Quite easy once you know how.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, using HTML5's server-side-events.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$reset = "true";
echo "data: reset: {$reset}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

on the server, and

```
<script>
var source = new EventSource("gsim_server.php");
source.onmessage = function(event)
{
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = event.data;
};
</script>
<div id="result">test</div>
```

on the client (asuming the server file is in the same folder and is called 'gsim_server.php'. This is just a basic example, but you could use the value passed to decide wether to reset or not. Hope that helps.

Comment: its really wow, I have checked one demo on https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, but still I am not sure how to use it, please can you share any demo for timer? using fiddle or something?

Comment: Hmm, big stories. I have done this before but cannot for the life of me find the source code. So...... I am editing my answer instead. (comments are too short)

Comment: how to pass any value from client to server here?

Comment: Well, instead of sending simply "true" you could send the time remaining. Meaning in the servers php file you have a fixed start time, calculate the time remaining, and pass that time remaining as a string to the clients php file which simply displays the time left. For you to reset all you do is edit the server php file changing the start time, so the client time remaining will then be changed the moment you save the server file. If that makes no sense let me know and I will set up a working sample on my server for you to see it in action.

Comment: Yes please can you setup a demo that will be really great

Comment: The test is at www.southcoasthosting.com/timer/timer.php . To reset the timer use the form at www.southcoasthosting.com/timer/timer.php. NB, the http certificate has expired, so just ignore. I will pos the code here as a new answer as it won't fit in comments.